# Basis change matrix for polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra

> $\mathcal{B}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}_3 [X]$.
>
> We have the polynomials:
>
> $\begin{cases}
> P_0 = 1, \\
> P_1 = 1 - X, \\
> P_2 = X - X^2, \\
> P_3 = X^2 - X^3. \\
> \end{cases} $ and $ \begin{cases}
> Q_0 = 1, \\
> Q_1 = 1 + X, \\
> Q_2 = 1 + X + X^2, \\
> Q_3 = 1 + X + X^2 + X^3. 
> \end{cases} $
>
> 1. Prove that $P = 3X - X^2 + 8X^3$ can be expressed as linear combination of the polynomials $P_0,P_1,P_2,P_3$ and determine the coefficients.
> 2. Prove that the $\mathcal{B_1} = (P_0, P_1, P_2, P_3)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}_3 [X]$ and determine the matrix $P_1$ of change of basis from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{B}_1$.
> 3. Prove that $\mathcal{B}_2 = (Q_0, Q_1, Q_2, Q_3)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}_3[X]$ and determine the matrix $P_2$ of change of basis from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{B}_2$.
> 4. Applying the formula of basis change on a vector, find the results of question $1$.

---

I have found:

1. $P = 10P_0 - 10P_1 - 7P_2 - 8P_3  $

The coefficients are: $10, -10, - 7$ and $- 8$.

2. $\mathcal{B_1}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}_3[X]$.

$P_{\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B_1}} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

3. $\mathcal{B_2}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}_3[X]$.

$P_{\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B_2}} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Are basis change matrices correct?

4. The basis change formula is: $B = P^{-1}.A.P$. I don't know how to find the results of question 1 using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please bear with me if you know the initial part of this answer.

---

How do we write a matrix transformation? Given $(V,B_V)$ and $(W,B_W)$, where $V,W$ are vector spaces with bases $B_V,B_W$ respectively, and a linear transformation $T : V \to W$, how do we write the matrix for $T$, with respect to $B_V$ and $B_W$?

1. Arrange $B_V,B_W$ in  some order.
2. Find where the elements of $B_V$ go under $T$.
3. Express the image vectors in terms of the basis $B_W$, and write the coefficients as columns one after the other to get a matrix.

For example, if $T : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, both with standard bases, is given by $T(x) = -x$, then we find where $(1,0)$ goes : it goes to $(-1,0)$ in the standard basis, and then find where $(0,1)$ goes : it goes to $(0,-1)$ in the standard basis. Therefore, the matrix of $T$ will be : first column $(-1,0)$, second column $(0,-1)$. You can see that you will get minus the identity matrix if you put this together, for the matrix of $T$.

---

Now, what is a change of basis matrix? Here is a nice interpretation :

> The change of basis matrix from basis $A$ to basis $B$ (in a vector space $V$), is the matrix of the *identity* linear transformation from $(V,A)$ to $(V,B)$.

That is,  find where all elements of $A$ go, and express them in basis $B$.

---

What have you done? For the change of basis matrix from $B$ to $B_1$, this is the matrix of the identity map from $(V,B)$ to $(V,B_1)$. So, *express the elements of $B$ in terms of the elements of $B_1$*. You have done *the opposite. You expressed $B_1$ in  terms of $B$*, when you wrote own your change of basis matrix.

The same with the third question.

---

Consequently, we see that the change of basis matrices are *the inverses* of what you have written, because base conversion needs to go  the other way. The right answer for b and c, therefore, is the inverse of the matrices you have written.

---

Finally, for $d$, of course the given polynomial can be interpreted as an element of $(V,B)$. Now, to change the basis to $B_1$ we want to shift to $(V,B_1)$, so simply multiply the change of basis matrix you have with you, and  the vector expressed in $B_1$.

That is, the inverse of the $P_{B,B_1}$ which you got, when multiplied with $[0,3,-1,8]^T$, gives you $[10,-10,-7,-8]$. You can check this is right.

Comment: $P_{ \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B_1} } = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1  & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ and 

$P_{ \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B_2} } = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0  & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & - 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ 

Are the matrices correct? Thank you so much for explaining the concept to me.

Comment: You are welcome, but did you find the matrix inverse of $P_{B,B_1}$? The first matrix is not correct. You can check  the right answer here :   http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(%5B%5B1,1,0,0%5D,%5B0,-1,1,0%5D,%5B0,0,-1,1%5D,%5B0,0,0,-1%5D%5D%5E(-1)) The answer to the second is right! Nevertheless, good job.

Comment: I have found $P_{\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B}_1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$.

When I computed $ P_{\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B}_1}.  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \\ -1  \\ 8 \\ \end{pmatrix} $. I found: $ v_{\mathcal{B}_2} = \begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ -10 \\ -7  \\ - 8 \\ \end{pmatrix} $, which is the result I found in question 1. Am I correct? Thank you.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The base change matrices are correct. 
To prove the given polynomials form a basis, just note that the determinants of these matrices are nonzero.

For question 4, the formula $P^{-1}AP$ applies only to a matrix $A$. 
 Here we only have a vector $b$ with $[b]_\mathcal B =(0,3,-1,8)^T$. 
To express $[b]_{\mathcal B_1}$, calculate $P^{-1}$ (e.g. by manually expressing the standard basis elements by $P_i$'s) and then apply/verify
$$[b]_{\mathcal B_1}=P^{-1}[b]_\mathcal B$$
Note that, for a base change matrix $P:\mathcal B\leadsto\mathcal B_1$ and a square matrix $A$, the columns of $AP$ are just $A$ applied to the elements of $\mathcal B_1$, coordinated in $\mathcal B$, so $P^{-1}$ of this will contain the $\mathcal B_1$-coordinates of the same vectors.

Comment: $P^{-1}_{\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B_1}}$ ?